# Finding the hidden message in a BMP file

Tags: c++, file-io, bmp

I am working on a school project where we need to read in a BMP file, then change the pixels to reveal a hidden message.

I am reading in the header first and storing it into an array. I know that I need to make only the Red in the RGB shows up to reveal the message. Also, red, blue, and green each take up one byte of space.

My teacher gave us code to get the height and width out of the header. I think that I am really close to figuring it out, but I keep getting errors throwing a `bad_alloc` exception. I assume that this means I am doing something wrong with the way I am storing the values or their pointers in memory.

While debugging, the errors are thrown from my exe files and not from my `main.cpp`. I have tried messing around with different things, but I am not sure how to handle this. I can't run my code to see if I am swapping the pixels and outputting correctly.

Oh, one last thing, the RGB is in the order of blue, green, red for some reason, but that's what our professor told us.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = std::fopen("output.bmp", "wb+");
    if (fp == nullptr) {
        //Error
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the output file\n";
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *cp = std::fopen("clue.bmp", "r");
    if (cp == nullptr) {
        //Error
        std::cout << "Failed to open the clue file\n";
        return 1;
    }
    uint8_t* header = NULL;
    header = new uint8_t[54];
    uint8_t* buf;
    buf = new uint8_t[54];

    if (std::fread(&buf, sizeof(header), 1, cp) != 1) {
        std::cout << "Failed to fread\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    buf == header;

    if (std::fwrite(&header[0], sizeof(header), 1, fp) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed fwrite for  output\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }
    int32_t width = *(static_cast<int *>(static_cast<void *>(&header[18])));
    int32_t height = *(static_cast<int *>(static_cast<void *>(&header[22])));
    uint64_t pixelCount;
    pixelCount = width * height;
    std::cout << "Number of pixels: " << pixelCount << "\n";
    uint8_t *pixels;
    pixels = new uint8_t[pixelCount];
    uint16_t byte;
    if (std::fseek(cp, sizeof(header), SEEK_SET) != 0) { //adjust pointer to avoid the header
        std::cerr << "Failed fseek\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (std::fread(&pixels, pixelCount, 1, cp) != 1) { 
        std::cout << "Failed to fread\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int i = 0;

    while (true) {
        for (i; i <= sizeof(byte)-1; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    if (std::fwrite(&pixels, pixelCount, 1, fp) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to fwrite pixels\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `new` for fixed-size arrays, just do `uint8_t header[54];`

Comment: Open your input file in binary mode. `buf == header` is testing for equality, not assigning anything. Of course if you fix that you'll find you have a memory leak and didn't make a copy of anything. You should choose if you're going to use `header` or `buf`, because what you have now reads into one and uses the other, which is uninitialized. I can't see any reason you need both, and I also don't know why you need to seek, if you read or wrote the header you're in the right place in the file already.

Comment: I count at least four major bugs in the first part of the program, that works with the BMP header. I don't even know where to start. There are fundamental problems here, with the understanding of how pointers work. I don't think that pointing out each and every bug here will be useful, here. Need to brush up on some C++ fundamentals, first and foremost.

Comment: `&buf` is the wrong memory address to read into when `buf` is a pointer. `sizeof(header)` is the wrong size to read/write when `header` is a pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(header)` is the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes), not the 54 bytes of the header. Changing it to an array will solve that.

Comment: You have some simple errors in your program, but all things considered it isn't that bad. Here's how I might fix it: https://ideone.com/lmteOJ Keep in mind that your input file must be a multiple of 4 in width, otherwise you'll need to deal with padding each line which I did not do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the outstanding advice and thank you everyone else

Comment: this is my first time using c++ so im new to this

Answer (score 0):

Your are misusing pointers and arrays.

You shouldn't be using `fopen()` in C++ at all, use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` instead.

You are not taking into account that the bitmap's height may be positive (bottom-up) or negative (top-down), or that each pixel in your `clue.bmp` file is 3 bytes each, or that each line of pixels is padded to an even multiple of 4 bytes.  And when you are trying to clear pixel bytes, you are stuck in an endless loop.

See [Bitmap Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391.aspx) and [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) for more details about the layout of a BMP file.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::ifstream cp("clue.bmp");
    if (!cp.is_open()) {
        //Error
        std::cout << "Failed to open the clue file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t header[54];

    if (!cp.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header), sizeof(header))) {
        std::cout << "Failed to read\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((header[0] != 0x42) || (header[1] != 0x4D)) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a BMP file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint32_t size = *(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&header[14]));
    if (size != 40) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint32_t pixelsOffset = *(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&header[10]));
    if (size != 54) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint16_t planes = *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&header[26]));
    if (planes != 1) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint16_t bitCount = *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&header[28]));
    if (bitCount != 24) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint32_t compression = *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&header[30]));
    if (compression != 0) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int32_t width = *(reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&header[18]));
    int32_t height = *(reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&header[22]));

    if (width <= 0 || height == 0) {
        std::cout << "clue file has no pixels\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int32_t actualHeight = height;
    if (actualHeight < 0) actualHeight *= -1;

    uint64_t pixelCount = width * actualHeight;
    std::cout << "Number of pixels: " << pixelCount << "\n";

    uint32_t bytesPerLine = (((width * 24) + 31) & ~31) / 8;

    std::vector<uint8_t> pixels(bytesPerLine * actualHeight);

    if (!cp.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixels[0]), pixels.size())) { 
        std::cout << "Failed to read\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cp.close();

    int32_t row;
    uint8_t *pixel;

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < actualHeight; ++i) {
        row = (height > 0) ? (actualHeight - i - 1) : i;
        pixel = &pixels[row * bytesPerLine];
        for (int32_t j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            *pixel++ = 0; // clear blue
            *pixel++ = 0; // clear green
            ++pixel; // skip red
        }
    }

    std::ofstream fp("output.bmp", std::ios_base::trunc);
    if (!fp.is_open()) {
        //Error
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the output file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!fp.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header), sizeof(header))) {
        std::cerr << "Failed write for output\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!fp.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixels[0]), pixels.size())) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to write pixels\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, this would be easier to read and maintain if you use pre-defined structures and constants instead of hard-coded byte offsets and ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), eg:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

#include <windows.h>
// or, if you want to compile for non-Windows platforms, manually
// define the relevant bitmap structures and constants, and make sure
// the structures are aligned to 1-byte boundaries, such as with
// #pragma pack, #pragma align, alignas(), etc, depending on compiler... 

int main() {
    std::ifstream cp("clue.bmp");
    if (!cp.is_open()) {
        //Error
        std::cout << "Failed to open the clue file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t header[54];
    if (!cp.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header), sizeof(header))) {
        std::cout << "Failed to read\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    BITMAPFILEHEADER *bfh = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPFILEHEADER*>(header);
    if ((bfh->bfType != 0x4D42) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a BMP file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    BITMAPINFOHEADER *bih = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFOHEADER*>(bfh+1);
    if (bih->biSize != sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (bfh->bfOffBits != 54) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (bih->biPlanes != 1) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (bih->biBitCount != 24) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (bih->biCompression != BI_RGB) {
        std::cout << "clue file is not a supported BMP format\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int32_t width = bih->biWidth;
    int32_t height = bih->biHeight;

    if (width <= 0 || height == 0) {
        std::cout << "clue file has no pixels\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (height < 0) height *= -1;

    uint64_t pixelCount = width * height;
    std::cout << "Number of pixels: " << pixelCount << "\n";

    uint32_t bytesPerLine = (((width * 24) + 31) & ~31) / 8;

    std::vector<uint8_t> pixels(bytesPerLine * height);

    if (!cp.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixels[0]), pixels.size())) { 
        std::cout << "Failed to read\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cp.close();

    int32_t row;
    RGBTRIPLE *pixel;

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        row = (bih->biHeight > 0) ? (height - i - 1) : i;
        pixel = reinterpret_cast<RGBTRIPLE*>(&pixels[row * bytesPerLine]);
        for (int32_t j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            pixel[j]->rgbtBlue = 0;
            pixel[j]->rgbtGreen = 0;
        }
    }

    std::ofstream fp("output.bmp", std::ios_base::trunc);
    if (!fp.is_open()) {
        //Error
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the output file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!fp.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header), sizeof(header))) {
        std::cerr << "Failed write for output\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!fp.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixels[0]), pixels.size())) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to write pixels\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the special casing for upside down or right side up for this simple assignment. Pixels are pixels.

Comment: Sure, if you know the EXACT format of the BMP file ahead of time then you can omit many of the safety checks I showed.  But, if you want to process any BMP file generically, you should perform the checks so you know what format of file you are actually working with. When it comes to accessing the raw pixel data, there are MANY different combinations you would have to deal with